# Grpc client asynchrony (c++)

Tags: c++, client, grpc

I am trying to make an asynchrony client side with Grpc (in cpp),
I want my client to print for example every second a dot: "." and when he gets a sign from the server I want him to print that he got a sign from the server, in my example, it's enter: `\n`.
As long as it doesn't get that sign, it will continue to loop and print the dot '.'
my code below doesn't work properly because it seems it print the dot, but does not identify the sign from the server:

Client:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <thread>
#include "dts.grpc.pb.h"

using grpc::Channel;
using grpc::ClientContext;
using grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReader;
using grpc::Status;
using grpc::CompletionQueue;

class DTSClient{
    public:
        explicit DTSClient(std::string socket);
        ~DTSClient() {}

        void run() {
            while(true){
                EntryCreateRequest request;
                ClientContext context;
                EntryResponse response;
                CompletionQueue cq;
                Status status;
            
                unsigned int microsecond = 1000000;
                usleep(1 * microsecond); //sleeps for 1 second
                std::cout << "." << std::endl;
                
                auto reader = stub_->PrepareAsyncrun_stream(&context, request, &cq);
                reader->StartCall();

                std::cout << *(response.title().c_str()) <<std::endl;
                if (*(response.title().c_str()) == '\n') {
                    std::cout << "I got enter" << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "\n" << std::endl;
                }

                reader->Finish(&response, &status, (void*)1);

                
            
                
                }
                
        }

    
  void AsyncCompleteRpc() {
    void* got_tag;
    bool ok = false;
    CompletionQueue cq;
    EntryResponse response;

    while (cq.Next(&got_tag, &ok)) {
      if (ok) {
        GPR_ASSERT(got_tag == (void*)1);

        std::cout << "Greeter received: " << response.title() << std::endl;
      } else {
        std::cout << "RPC failed" << std::endl;
      }
    }
  }
    
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<grpc::Channel> channel_;
        std::unique_ptr<DTSService::Stub> stub_;

};

DTSClient::DTSClient(std::string socket_file) {
    std::string full_socket("unix://");
    full_socket += socket_file;
    channel_ = grpc::CreateChannel(full_socket, grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials());
    stub_ = DTSService::NewStub(channel_);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    DTSClient dts_client("/tmp/grpc.sock");
    std::cout << "Client start" << std::endl;


    std::thread thread_ = std::thread(&DTSClient::AsyncCompleteRpc, &dts_client);

    dts_client.run();

    thread_.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Server:

```
# import required libraries & proto defn.
import grpc
from concurrent import futures
import sys
import os
import logging
import time
import subprocess
import asyncio

sys.path.append("/labhome/rdomnitz/workspace/collectx/Collectx/services/dts/proto")
import dts_pb2_grpc, dts_pb2

# Host where the server starts 
SERVER_ADDRESS = "/tmp/grpc.sock"


class Listener(dts_pb2_grpc.DTSServiceServicer):
    """
    class to run a DPEService server (dpe.proto)
    """

    def run_command(self, request, context):
        cmd = request.command
    
        timeout = request.timeout
     
        logging.debug("run_command: %s", cmd)
        proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                            universal_newlines=True,
                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        try:
            std_out, std_err = proc.communicate(timeout=timeout)
            rcode = proc.returncode
            timeout_expired = False
        except Exception as exp:
            proc.kill()
            logging.error(f"run_command: {cmd} failed with error: {exp}")
            std_out, std_err, rcode, timeout_expired = self._TIMEOUT_COMMAND_RESPONSE_TUPLE
        return dts_pb2.RunCommandResponse(std_out=std_out, std_err=std_err,
                                rc=rcode, timeout_expired=timeout_expired)


    def run_stream(self, request, context):
        print("Wait for input")
        input = sys.stdin.read(1)
        yield dts_pb2.EntryResponse(title=input)



def main():
    try:
        server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor())

        dts_pb2_grpc.add_DTSServiceServicer_to_server(Listener(), server)     
        
        server.add_insecure_port(f"unix://{SERVER_ADDRESS}") 
        
        logging.debug("start server")
        server.start()
        server.wait_for_termination()
    
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("KeyboardInterrupt")
        server.stop(0)


# invoke the server method
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    main()
```

thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your approach in the client side code is that the `CompletionQueue` instance you are using to start your RPC is different from the one that you are driving in `AsyncCompleteRpc()`. (I haven't verified the rest of the code, but that was the main issue that I spotted.)

I would recommend using the C++ Callback API instead of the CQ-based API. The Callback API is much more intuitive and straightforward to use.
You would find some examples here - https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples